# Monoidal colimit-preserving functor from spaces to $A$-modules

Tags: stable-homotopy, derived-algebraic-geometry, ring-spectra

I am reading Lurie's Elliptic Cohomology II and it claims (Section 4.1.3) that for an $\mathbb{E}_\infty$-ring $A$ "there is an essentially unique symmetric monoidal functor $\mathcal{S} \to \operatorname{Mod}_A$ which preserves small colimits", where $\mathcal{S}$ is the category of spaces.

At first I thought this would be the map $X \mapsto \Sigma^\infty X \wedge A$. As spectra, it preserves small colimits, but I am not sure this is the case as $A$-modules. Does anyone have a more explicit description of this functor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description of the functor is correct. The suspension spectrum functor is homotopy colimit preserving, as you say. Smashing with A is left adjoint to the forgetful functor from A-modules to spectra, and this means that it also preserves homotopy colimits.

Comment: As a remark: the forgetful fuctor $Spectra \to Mod_A$ is also conservative, and has a right adjoint (the function spectrum $X \mapsto F(A,X)$). This means that not only does the forgetful functor preserve colimits, but also that colimits in $Mod_A$ can be _detected_ by checking if they are colimits in $Spectra$.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean the forgetful functor $Mod_A \to Spectra$?

Comment: @SofíaMarlascaAparicio Yes, sorry.